# How to write all DateTime fields as ISO 8601 strings?

Tags: c#, csv, iso8601, csvhelper

I'm writing CSV out of `IEnumerable<dynamic>` objects. I do not know how many `DateTime` fields these objects can have, nor its names.

Is there a way to tell `CsvWriter` to write all DateTime objects as ISO 8601 strings?

```cs
var records = new List<dynamic>();

dynamic record = new ExpandoObject();
record.Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
records.Add(record);

using (var writer = new StringWriter())
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    csv.WriteRecords(records);
    writer.ToString().Dump(); // I want the DateTime to be in ISO 8601 format (2020-05-01T15:29:19Z)
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/1ng5W9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TypeConverterOptions` and apply the options to `DateTime`.

```
using (var writer = new StringWriter())
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    var options = new TypeConverterOptions { Formats = new [] {"s"} };
    //apply options to datetime
    csv.Configuration.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<DateTime>(options);

    csv.WriteRecords(records);
    writer.ToString().Dump();
}

// output
// 2020-05-01T16:02:36
```

This uses `"s"` (sortable datetime format).
You could apply any format you like, for example: `Formats = new [] { "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" }` will give similar result.

See updated [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PM4psK).